# Java Reflection. Running a external jar and referring to its classes?

Tags: java, class, reflection

This code snippet allows me to run a jar as part of my program:

```
File f = new File("client.jar");
URLClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{f.toURI().toURL(), null});
Class<?> clazz = cl.loadClass("epicurus.Client");
Method main = clazz.getMethod("main", String[].class);
main.invoke(null, new Object[]{new String[]{}});
```

Is there anyway that I can refer to that external program's classes?
I want to be able to change the title of its JFrame for instance.

Comment: The title attribute is on **instances** of JFrame, not the class.  While you can inspect classes with reflection, you can't manipulate instances.

Comment: @SteveH. - Huh? Of course you can ... that's kinda the point of reflection. `Field.set(objInstance, fieldValue)` ... there you go, I just manipulated an instance.

Comment: @BrianRoach you're right- maybe I should say you can't "obtain" instances.  How would you know that a new JFrame was created and where would you obtain the reference?  My assumption is that the jar file is  unknown

Comment: @SteveH. - Erm, you'd ... do what the guy posted in the answer below.

Comment: @BrianRoach Erm..  except that it won't work except when the JFrames are already instantiated.  But thanks for the snarkiness.

Comment: But ... it is instantiated? That wasn't meant to be snarky, more a restatement of "huh?"; the way I read it he was talking about wanting to change the title of the main window (or something that is instantiated/being displayed, anyway) since he's already invoked `main`. You're absolutely correct in that if it's something that hasn't been created yet he's hosed

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24149/discussion-between-steve-h-and-brian-roach)

Answer (score 3):

I believe you could. I'd attempt as follows.

After invoking the main, you'll want to run a loop to access the Window you're interested in (can be done in a separate thread).

```
for(Window window : Window.getWindows()){
    if(window != null && window.isVisible() && window instanceof JFrame){
        JFrame jFrame = (JFrame)window;
    }
}
```

You can then access the JFrame's fields and methods (or if necessary, specify that the frame you are modifying is the one you intend by comparing jFrame.getName() and some String) via reflection.

Say for example you are interested in modifying the font size and style in a JTextArea.

```
Field textAreaField = jFrame.getClass().getDeclaredField("textArea");
textAreaField.setAccessible(true);
```

Would allow you access to the field and permit you to modify it in any way you see fit.

From there you'll need the actual object.

```
JTextArea textArea = (JTextArea) textAreaField.get(jFrame);

Font font = textArea.getFont();
textArea.setFont(new Font(font.getFontName(), font.getStyle(), 24));
```

And that should just about do it for you.